# BottomSheetDialogFragment jumps on top of status bar, when change view's visibility and focus an EditText

Tags: android, bottomsheetdialogfragment

I have a BottomSheetDialogFragment in my project. Because of some special requirements when the input value is a number I have to use a custom keyboard (Custom View). When focus editText, I hide the system keyboard and change the visibility of the custom keyboard from GONE to VISIBLE. However, I have a very annoying problem. when the focus edittext bottom sheet jumps up and sticks to the status bar, and the overlay is pushed back down. Since the project is quite large, I think there are some places where there may be conflicts, I have created a new project but not having the problem mentioned again. So I was wondering if anyone has had the same problem as me, and can suggest me some ways to solve it. Thanks.

[image: Image describes my problem]

[Expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zpA9r.png)
Does anyone had the same problem or any idea how to fix this strange jumps

**UPDATE:** the solution is remove animateLayoutChange attributes in layout XML file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Styles:

```
<style name="BottomSheetDialogThemeNoFloating" parent="Theme.Design.Light.BottomSheetDialog">
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">adjustResize</item>
</style>
```

Add this in the dialog

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add_or_edit_product, container, false)
```

Comment: I have tried this, but the result is still the same.